# How can I pass a value in a variable to a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

So I’m using https://github.com/and-who/react-p5-wrapper to create p5.js in React.

I’m wondering if there’s a way to pass a value from the p5 Sketch file back into React? For example. I want to keep track of the **label** value generated in p5 Sketch and use that somewhere later. How can I store that value globally?

```
export default function sketch(p5) {

    function modelReady() {
        console.log("Model is ready!!!")
        mobilenet.predict(gotResults)
    }

    function gotResults(error, results) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error)
        } else {
            **label = results[0].label** <-- This badboy
            mobilenet.predict(gotResults)
        }
    }
```

The thing that I'm building https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-wave-dgrlg (it's a machine learning cam that will detect what the camera is seeing) You can see that the label within <s>React is not updating but it's only updating the label in the p5 sketch.</s>

**My fix:** I have done something like `setInterval(setLabel, 0)` in my code but that doesn't seem to be the correct pattern? Is there a better way?

**Solution:** https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-gates-usew3

Comment: if you put this code inside the mounting logic like `useEffect` of a react component you can save that information in react state. or "hackier" ways like putting the value on the window object or in localstorage

Comment: A [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) may help here. It can use a defined handler to notify your react component that a label value change has occurred. Can you include your react code as well?

Comment: @DrewReese added my full code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-wave-dgrlg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I store that value globally?

For global states, use redux store. You can dispatch an action to store this label.

**NOTE**, as stated in the [README](https://github.com/and-who/react-p5-wrapper#usage),

> `myCustomRedrawAccordingToNewPropsHandler` function is called if Properties of the wrapper component are changing

So I'm sharing the sketch object to be explicit. This redraw function will be used to access the parent function that actually dispatches to redux store.

```
// sketch
export default function sketch(p) {
  // use custom redraw handler
  p.myCustomRedrawAccordingToNewPropsHandler = function (props) {
    // TODO: replace with actual label
    // get value out
    setInterval(() => props.gotResults(null, "done"), 5000);
  };
}
```

```
// action
const key = "p5";
const SAVE_LABEL = `${key}/SAVE_LABEL`;

// action creator
function saveLabel(label) {
  return {
    type: SAVE_LABEL,
    payload: {
      label
    }
  }
}

export default function Sketch(props) {
  // dispatch inside component
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  function gotResults(error, label) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
    }

    dispatch(saveLabel(label));
  }

  return (
    <P5Wrapper
      sketch={sketch}
      gotResults={gotResults}
    />
  );
}

// TODO: add reducer
```

Sample sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-breeze-54mde

Comment: How does OP get `dispatch` and action creator *into* the sketch object so `sketch` can "dispatch" it?

Comment: it's part of the todo list that leads to learning. :)

Comment: Right... but the `sketch` function is a p5.js object, not a `Sketch` react component, so `gotResults` isn't in React. Does this answer address, or explain resolution of, OP's issue of getting a value *out of* the p5 sketch? At least attempt to relate your solution code to that of the OP.

Comment: Yes. apologies. I may have omitted important info. Anyway, added the sketch object to show how to get value out.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks. I didn't know `p5.myCustomRedrawAccordingToNewPropsHandler` property can be a 2 way door. I thought only values can be pass in from React --> p5 but not the other way round.

Another problem that I quickly face is that the `label` that I have is a dynamic label that will get updated all the time but the value that get passed over is just a static value in time. I tried using React.useEffects but can't get it working. Any ideas?

Comment: The thing that I'm building https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-wave-dgrlg (it's a machine learning cam that will detect what the camera is seeing) As you can see the label is updating within a p5 sketch but not within my React code.

Comment: Also not sure if `setInterval(setLabel, 0)` <-- Making the interval 0ms is actually "correct"? Is that a hacky way?

Comment: `setInterval` was just to show the state change. Anyway, here's a crude sample showing something similar. https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-snow-l1qx3

Comment: Ah cool! @JosephD. Thanks! I've figured that out. I've made some tweaks on my code. It's now working (: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-gates-usew3 That's for being so helpful.

Comment: @JosephD. Hi Joseph, can I trouble you again to pick your brain on some of the suggestions you put together for me. It's hard to describe within this box so I created a new comment on this page to add more clarity.

Comment: Anytime @Vennsoh. Added a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

@josephD I'm scratching my head trying to understand how this work in my code. Can you educate me on how this work? Thanks!

Based on this file, https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-gates-usew3

So in my **Sketch.tsx** file, I've this line of command `props.setLabel(label)` is this creating a React prop on the fly? We call it `setLabel` and assign a value `label` to it?

```
  p5.myCustomRedrawAccordingToNewPropsHandler = function (props) {
    gotResults = (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error)
        } else {
            label = results[0].label
            **props.setLabel(label)** <-- this bad boy
            mobilenet.predict(gotResults)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in our **App.tsx** file, it seems that we can pass the `setLabel` prop that we created from **Sketch.tsx** into it? I thought to use `React.useState` I need to type something like `setLabel(value)`? We don't need to call `setLabel(value)` anywhere within the **App.tsx** file?

```
    const [label, setLabel] = React.useState("...")

return (
    <>
        <Frame>{label}</Frame>
        <P5Wrapper sketch={sketch} setLabel={setLabel} /> <-- How this magic happen?
    </>
)
```

The `setLabel` from the useState is now a prop in P5Wrapper? And it's taking in the `setLabel` from **Sketch.tsx** as an attribute?

My definition of attribute and prop:
**attribute={prop}**

const [label, **setLabel**] = React.useState("...")

<P5Wrapper sketch={sketch} *setLabel*={**setLabel**} /> <-- **setLabel** as a prop? *setLabel* from Sketch.tsx as an attribute?

Comment: This concept is called [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Where the state (`label`) is in App (parent component), then the only way to update this state is via `setLabel`. `setLabel` in App is passed down as prop to the child component (P5Wrapper) so that the child component can have the means to update the parent state.